# Can't run ionic 2 app in Genymotion Android emulator

Tags: android, genymotion, ionic2

My ionic 2 application can't be run in Genymotion Android emulator. The error message is:

> ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: adb: Command failed
>   with exit code 1 Error output: error: could not install *smartsocket*
>   listener: Address already in use ADB server didn't ACK
>   * failed to start daemon * error: cannot connect to daemon You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project

It seems the port number is taken already. But it works fine for normal AVD emulator when I stop the Genymotion emulator.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fixed the problem by changing the settings in Genymotion.

[image]

Comment: This worked. You'll need to restart the Genymotion virtual device and then run `ionic run android`, not `ionic emulate android`